How to receive data from android Service
I have a foreground service that runs FusedLocationProviderClient. It gets gps location updates every 20 seconds.
What is the most proper way to send location data from service to activity? Use broadcast messages? Or may be there is a way to use flows? Or anything else?
Thanks

Bind to the service.  When you do that, the Service returns a binder object.  That object can be anything you want, and can include a full API to the service.  You can have it include a flow or other observable object and subscribe to that.

"That object can be anything you want, and can include a full API to the service" -- note that this is true only if the service and the activity are in the same process. If they are in different processes, then you will be limited to AIDL-supported types. Personally, for the case where both are in the same process, I would skip binding and just have the service and the activity both work with other architectural elements, such as a repository.
